# Android - How can I pass camera stream to ffmpeg, using Camera2 library?

Tags: android, ffmpeg, udp, android-camera2

I am trying to create an app that shows the camera of the device on the screen, and also streams the camera by srt. To do this, I am using Camera2 library, and ffmpeg (in partucular I am using https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg, that is a ffmpeg wrapper for Android).

My plan is to get the camera stream using Camera2 (using the method onImageAvailable on ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener class), and send this stream to udp://localhost:1234. Then, I can use ffmpeg to get that stream by udp, and send it by srt.

I've already solved the part of sending the stream by srt using ffmpeg, and it works fine. In fact, if I set "android_camera" as the input of my ffmpeg command, my app works ok. The problem with this approach, is that if I do that, I block the access to the camera, so I can't show the camera on the screen with another library.

I also found a code that uses Camera2 to stream the camera by udp, and it works, but the problem with this code is that converts each frame to bitmap before sending it by udp, and it makes that it is not performant.

So, I need to know which is the best way to pass the data by udp to ffmpeg, so ffmpeg could process it and send it by srt?

Camera2 let me to configure which format I want to receive the frames on my listener:

```
ImageReader.newInstance(1280, 720, ImageFormat.JPEG, /*maxImages*/2);
```

In this example I am setting JPEG as ImageFormat, but here I let you all the available formats I could use:

UNKNOWN, RGB_565, YV12, Y8, Y16, NV16, NV21, YUY2, JPEG, DEPTH_JPEG, YUV_420_888, YUV_422_888, YUV_444_888, FLEX_RGB_888, FLEX_RGBA_8888, RAW_SENSOR, RAW_PRIVATE, RAW10, RAW12, DEPTH16, DEPTH_POINT_CLOUD, RAW_DEPTH, PRIVATE, HEIC

This is the method where I am going to receive each frame, and what I need to know is what kind of transformation I have to do before sending the frame by udp to ffmpeg?:

```
@Override
public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {

}
```

Thanks in advance for reading the question :)

Answer (score 0):

On the camera side, you'll likely want to use YUV_420_888, since that's the guaranteed to be supported format by all color cameras.  That's a 4:2:0 subsampled YUV buffer.

I don't know what FFMPEG will accept over udp; you'll have to read its documentation (or code) for figuring that out.  But most likely, FFMPEG will support some kind of YUV 4:2:0 format, like NV21, YV12, etc.   Ideally it'll support something flexible with adjustable row and pixel stride, as Android's YUV_420_888 format does.  But if not, you'll need to swizzle the YUV data to match the layout FFMPEG requires.